# How do I stop chrome from redirecting me due to malicious software

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, malware-removal

When I click some links in chrome (trusted websites), I get redirected to 'spam' websites that say "your computer has viruses" or something stupid like that. How do I stop it from doing this? I have run 
numerous virus removal tools including:

AVG

Norton

Malwarebytes

Trojan Killer

Google's software removal tool

Adwcleaner

Ccleaner

Windows Defender

I also reset chrome

I did find a number of viruses, but got rid of them. This is still happening and is starting to get annoying. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: As you had "a number of viruses" it is also possible that your router has been compromised - if you set the DNS lookup on the computer manually to, say, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (those are Google DNS server addresses [Using Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)) and you are no longer redirected to malware, then look to resetting your router.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to handle malware, though I would first reccommend going through your downloads and removing any you don't need. Check your other files if there is nothing there, or try using a program designed to clean out unneccessary files, such as mycleanpc.com or something. There is also a chance you have an addon to Chrome you don't want, in which case you click the three bars in the top right, and go to More Tools, then Extentions. Check there for addons you don't want. Good luck!

Comment: I have already tried all this... no luck yet.